# Ubuntu 14.04 installation issue - Keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: keyboard, 14.04, mouse, system-installation

After installing the new Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS, the keyboard and mouse are not working.

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed and I want to update to the last version (14.04), so I installed the new version in a new hard disk.

During installation the keyboard and mouse worked fine, after reboot the keyboard and mouse didn't work anymore.
If I try to unplug any of them and then I reconnect them, sometimes the system halts.

I have a motherboard ECS C51GM-M, and the keyboard and mouse are PS/2.

It's important to mention that in Ubuntu version 10.10, all still works fine.

Finally, I want to clarify that I'm new in Ubuntu, I haven't installed the previous version.

Comment: How did you installed Ubuntu? From a USB drive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simptnon!
No, i installed it from a DVD burned with the ISO image downloaded from Ubuntu website.

Comment: Can you test it with a USB-Keyboard? Perhaps this helps http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/157789-SOLVED!-Ubuntu-13-10-keybored-and-mouse-stops-working-after-some-time! or http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/477487-new-install-12-1-64bit-ps2-mouse-amp-keyboard-not-working-after-booting

Comment: Yes, i have tested it with USB keyborad and mouse, but nothing. I'll see that links. Thanks!

Comment: [You can not hotplug PS/2 devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port#Hotplugging) - that is why it crashes when you try to unplug them

Comment: Can you ssh in to the PC after booting (with the keyboard and mouse plugged in)?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after updating. I can't use my keyboard/mouse if I  load the latest Linux kernel, (Linux 3.13.0-24-generic) but if I choose an older one (Linux 3.11.0-19) under Advanced options for Ubuntu in GRUB it works for me.

I have a PS/2 keyboard and USB mouse.

Not sure if that helps on your new install though, it might not have shipped with other kernel versions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, mouse and keyboard working fine in the installer but nothing at all working when the system booted.

I used unetbootin for writing the USB stick from which I installed. After switching to Universal USB installer and reinstalling the system, everything is now working fine.